# The repository 'https://apt.repos.intel.com/mpi all Release' is no longer signed during `apt-get upgrade` in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates

I'm trying to upgrade ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, but the first step gives me this error.

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for ckim: 
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-2-148-local-patch-1  InRelease
Ign:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-2-148-local-patch-1  InRelease
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-2-local  InRelease
Ign:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-2-local  InRelease
Get:4 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-11-1-local  InRelease
Ign:4 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-11-1-local  InRelease
Get:5 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  Release [574 B]
Get:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-2-148-local-patch-1  Release [574 B]
Get:7 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-2-local  Release [574 B]
Get:8 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-11-1-local  Release [564 B]
Get:5 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  Release [574 B]
Get:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-2-148-local-patch-1  Release [574 B]
Get:7 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-2-local  Release [574 B]
Get:8 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-11-1-local  Release [564 B]
Hit:12 https://apt.repos.intel.com/daal all InRelease                                                                                                                  
Hit:13 https://apt.repos.intel.com/ipp all InRelease                                                         
Hit:15 https://apt.repos.intel.com/mkl all InRelease                                                         
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]                                  
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                     
Hit:19 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-xenial InRelease                                                                                          
Hit:20 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                           
Get:21 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                                                           
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                         
Hit:23 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                   
Get:24 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [93.7 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [130 kB]         
Ign:27 https://apt.repos.intel.com/mpi all InRelease                        
Hit:28 https://apt.repos.intel.com/tbb all InRelease                        
Hit:29 https://apt.repos.intel.com/intelpython binary/ InRelease                                        
Get:30 https://apt.repos.intel.com/mpi all Release [3,865 B]                                             
Get:31 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [326 kB]
Get:32 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]            
Err:33 https://apt.repos.intel.com/mpi all Release.gpg                                               
  403  Forbidden
Get:34 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [249 kB]
Get:35 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [281 kB]
Get:36 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,964 B]                                                                   
Get:37 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]                                                                       
Get:38 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [6,612 B]                                                                   
Hit:11 https://apt.llvm.org/xenial llvm-toolchain-xenial-7 InRelease                                                                                                   
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                          
E: The repository 'https://apt.repos.intel.com/mpi all Release' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Here is the /proc/cpuinfo (it's 28 core, so I attach only the first core info)

```
processor : 0
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model : 85
model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-7940X CPU @ 3.10GHz
stepping : 4
microcode : 0x2006a08
cpu MHz : 1200.008
cache size : 19712 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 28
core id : 0
cpu cores : 14
apicid : 0
initial apicid : 0
fpu : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp : yes
flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single pti ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req md_clear flush_l1d
bugs : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs taa itlb_multihit
bogomips : 6199.99
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is no longer in *standard* spport, and many repositories are erased on a release reaching EOL (last day of *standard* support was actually 29-April-2021 for 16.04 with ESM starting on 30-April-2021) https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/  so I'd remove the 3rd party sources (`ppa-purge`) as your question is now off-topic unless it's specific to the *release-upgrade* step on this site.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as 16.04 has ended it's *standard* support stage.

Comment: @guiverc yes, I was aware of the EOL. but since I have to do the release-upgrade, I can't do  the ppa-purge(Did I get it correct?). I'm not sure if this EOL prevents the release upgrade too(I think they should proved at least the release upgrade path, I'm not sure..).

Comment: *release-upgrade* will work whilst 18.04 is still in *standard* support... technically I still believe the Ubuntu *xenial* repositories are still open (`grub+shim` packages still haven't made it to 'main' in *arm64* last I heard & I look almost hourly, which once completed will allow closing; that was delayed as was intended to occur 29-April).  3rd party packages often cause *release-upgrade* issues thus the recommended to `ppa-purge` (ie. remove the 3rd party packages, not just sources!)

Comment: Comment out the source and try again. Considering how many third-party sources you have, it might be prudent to backup your data and be prepared for a clean-install of 18.04 (or 20.04) if the release-upgrade fails. It was not tested with that mix of sources.

Comment: ok, I was reading about ppa-purge and might try that or commenting out. thanks! ADD : I just comment out the line and the apt-get update ran ok. I'll proceed with the release upgrade. thanks.